creating case_when function with two inputs, one numeric and one string
I have to do a bunch of conditional recodes where the variable to be recoded is numeric but the conditional variable is string. I've created a function that takes the two variables as input and then use the case_when function to make the change in the numeric variable if a condition based on the string variable is true, with a .default condition to retain the original value of the numeric variable.
I'm getting an error that says:
Error in `case_when()`:
! Can't combine `..1 (right)` <double> and `..2 (right)` <character>.

Here's a simple example:
library("dplyr")
library("data.table")
library("Hmisc")

v1 = c(1:8)
v2 = c(2:9)
v3 = c(3:10)
c1 = c("ab","bc","cd","de","ef","fg","gh","hi")
c2 =c("gh","hi","ab","bc","cd","de","ef","fg")
c3 = c("bc","cd","de","ef","fg","gh","hi","ab")

df = data.frame(v1,v2,v3,c1,c2,c3)
df

# replace v column value with 99 if the corresponding c column starts with "b"
# so that the contents of df would be
#   v1  v2   v3 c1 c2 c3
# 1  1   2   99 ab gh bc
# 2  99  3   4  bc hi cd
# 3  3   4   5  cd ab de
# 4  4   99  6  de bc ef
# 5  5   6   7  ef cd fg
# 6  6   7   8  fg de gh
# 7  7   8   9  gh ef hi
# 8  8   9  10  hi fg ab

xlist=paste("v",1:3,sep="")
xlist

ylist=paste("c",1:3,sep="")
ylist

myfunc <- function(x,y) {
  x = case_when (
    substr(y,1,1)=="b" ~ 99,
    TRUE ~ x )
}

df = lapply(xlist,myfunc,y=ylist)

Here is the content of df as displayed by the command after the data.frame is created:
  v1 v2 v3 c1 c2 c3
1  1  2  3 ab gh bc
2  2  3  4 bc hi cd
3  3  4  5 cd ab de
4  4  5  6 de bc ef
5  5  6  7 ef cd fg
6  6  7  8 fg de gh
7  7  8  9 gh ef hi
8  8  9 10 hi fg ab

What am I missing about the .default command (same problem if is use the TRUE keyword)?

Use df[xlist] <- Map(myfunc, df[xlist], df[ylist]) and it will work.  The issue is that you're passing the function column names instead of the data from the columns.  You also should be using Map() to iterate over multiple inputs in parallel and not lapply().

The problems in the question are:

the code is passing the names to myfunc but myfunc is defined in terms of the values.
we need to arrange that corresponding elements of xlist and ylist are used
case_when is from dplyr and the library statement is missing
although case_when is not wrong ifelse seems preferable in this case in which case we don't need dplyr; however, to keep consistent with the question we will use myfunc as presented there.

Using df, myfunc, xlist and ylist from the question:
library(dplyr)

replace(df, xlist, mapply(myfunc, x = df[xlist], y = df[ylist]))

giving
  v1 v2 v3 c1 c2 c3
1  1  2 99 ab gh bc
2 99  3  4 bc hi cd
3  3  4  5 cd ab de
4  4 99  6 de bc ef
5  5  6  7 ef cd fg
6  6  7  8 fg de gh
7  7  8  9 gh ef hi
8  8  9 10 hi fg ab

